# how capture click in notification with app closed to redirect a specific page in firebase messaging > 9.0

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, flutter-dependencies

I am using version 9.0 of firebase messaging and wishing the user to a specific screen when receiving and clicking on a notification when the app is closed.

I can currently manage with the app open or minimized, but I don't understand how to perform this action when the app is not open.

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  Model model = Model();
  id = "sasassa;
  Get.offNamed("$SCREEN_ROUTE",arguments: model);
  Storage storage = Storage();
  storage.setReceivedNotification(true);
  print("teste notificação recebida");

}

FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message){
    if (message != null){
      Model model = Model();
      id = "sasassa;
      Get.offNamed("$SCREEN_ROUTE",arguments: model);
    }
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    print("a");
    storage.setReceivedNotification(true);
    Model model = Model();
    id = "sasassa;
    Get.offNamed("$SCREEN_ROUTE",arguments: model);
    //Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/events');
  });


  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    print("b");
    storage.setReceivedNotification(true);
    print("teste b $message");
    String? corpo = message.notification?.body;
    String? titulo = message.notification?.title;
    String? image = message.notification?.android?.imageUrl;
    //showMyDialog(titulo: titulo,corpo: corpo);

    print("$corpo $titulo $image");

  });
```

I tried to use shared preference in backgroundHandler, but this way the redirect will happen even without the user clicking on the notification.

Would anyone have instructions on how to redirect a with the app closed from the click on a specific notification?

PS: I know I need to send the data in the notification body, I just want to understand how to make the flutter capture the click with the app closed in version 9.0 or higher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()`  method to get messages

If App is Closed/Killed

```
  FirebaseMessaging.instance
          .getInitialMessage()
          .then((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("FirebaseMessaging.getInitialMessage $message");
   });
```

Use `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp`  method to get messages

If App is in background

```
   FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp
            .listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp $message");
   });
```

Use `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage`  method will receive a message

If App is in foreground

```
   FirebaseMessaging.onMessage
         .listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("FirebaseMessaging.onMessage $message");
   });
```